# How secure is jasypt?

Tags: java, security, encryption, jasypt

I have recently made an app that uses jasypt APIs for encryption and decryption of text and Passwords.
My question is, if the hacker also uses or knows about jasypt, would it be possible for him to use the decrypt() method to decrypt my encrypted data?
How do i make sure that another person who's also using jasypt cannot decrypt my data?

Comment: Since jasypt provides only symmetric encryption, you will have to keep the key/password from the attacker. Whether this is at all possible would depend on your explicit scenario/use case. You might want to describe that in detail.

Comment: @ArtjomB. Consider that i store encrypted passwords in the database, if somehow the attacker gets access to it, can he decrypt my data?

Comment: Only if you store or rather keep the key close to the data that it encrypted.

Comment: @ArtjomB. Where do i find this key you're talking about?

Comment: If you're using then you have to supply it with a key or a password. You should have it.

Answer (score 0):

I think so.  Say you have a Spring Boot application and you have **application.properties** file with username and password like:

```
# in application.properties
username=myuser
password=DEC(mypassword)
jasypt.encryptor.password=tester
```

Once you run jasypt command to encrypt above password, the **application.properteis** file will be modified and will look like:

```
# in application.properties
username=myuser
password=ENC(hlyNvWcMld4LeQUkExq3i9QD9i2x8U4c)
jasypt.encryptor.password=tester
```

If this file goes into a repository like a GitHub or SVN, there is nothing there to prevent malicuous user to take the `jasypt.encryptor.password` and use it to decrypt the password and endup with its original value `mypassword`.  There is even an online tool for that.

I think the same applies with Spring Cloud Config server where instead of `DEC()`, `END()`, `{cypher}` is being used.

To me, the only way around that is that the **application.properties** content cannot ever be pushed to a repo.  Or that different values are provided for development and production in which case even if you have the `jasypt.encryptor.password` in the **application.properties** and that is in GitHub, it is used only for development.

On deployment, the container will provide another password.  So, this would be "safe" but still, it disclosed internals about the application.  For example, attacker now knows that your application uses jasypt and relies on the correct `jasypt.encryptor.password`.